# Why List<? super Cat> list can't add Animal?

Tags: java

I am a novice, I met a problem, do not understand, as follows:

```
class Animal {}

class Cat extends Animal {}

class Garfield extends Cat {}

public class Demo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<? super Cat> list = new ArrayList<>(); // list can include cat and animal

        list.add(new Cat());      // perfect !!
        list.add(new Garfield()); // wait... why can ??
        list.add(new Animal());   // wait... why can't ?? 
    }
}
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: This line compiles for me: `list.add(new Garfield());`

Comment: a detailed answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/4343547/2216472

Comment: @markspace - as it does for the OP

Answer (score 3):

`? super Cat` means "`Cat` and it's superclasses, up to `Object`", so it can be either `List<Cat>` or `List<Animal>` - both are subtypes of `List<? super Cat>`.
You only know the lower bound (which is why it's called lower bounded wildcard), so you can add only objects of type `Cat` and it's descendants: they definitely can be added to collection, whichever the actual type of elements inside is - that's why you can add `new Cat()` and `new Garfield()` - they both are `Cat`s and `Animal`s.
But, you cannot add `Animal`s - since it can be a `List` of `Cat`, for example, and `Animal` is-not-a `Cat` (`Cat` is-an `Animal`). Same logic, you cannot assign an `Animal` value to a `Cat` variable, since `Cat` extends type of `Animal`, and `Animal`, therefore, lacks the new functionality `Cat` provides.

Comment: Oh! I see! Thank you very much!

Comment: Isn't `Animal` a superclass of `Cat`?

Comment: Yes, `Animal` is a superclass of `Cat`, but `? super Cat` might stand for `Feline` and an `Animal` is not a `Feline`. Basically to a `List<? super Cat>` you can only write `Cat` and read `Object` (it is a consumer of elements), from a `List<? extends Cat>` you can only read `Cat`s and write `null` (it is a supplier of elements).

Comment: I've updated the answer with more detailed explanation